# How to manage multiple states with one bloc for a single page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have **15** api to show home page. what is the best way to manage all 15 api status in one state?

I created 15 Status abstract classes and use them as constructor for state class and manage building each widget with `buildWhen`, but it's been very complex. What is the best practice?

HomeState class that pass to ui

```
class HomeState {
  Api1Status? api1status;
  Api2Status? api2Status;

  HomeState({
    this.api1status,
    this.api2Status,
  });

  HomeState copyWith({
    Api1Status? newApi1status,
    Api2Status? newApi2Status,
  }) {
    return HomeState(
      api1status: newApi1Status ?? this.api1status,
      api2Status: newApi2Status ?? this.api2Status,
    );
  }
}
```

each API status for managing its state

```
@immutable
abstract class Api1Status{}

class Api1Loading extends Api1Status{}

class Api1Completed extends Api1Status{
  final Api1Entity Api1Entity;
  Api1Completed(this.Api1Entity);
}

class Api1Error extends Api1Status{
  final String message;
  Api1Error(this.message);
}
```

and 14 more status classes for each API

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a DataState abstract class to manage state of each API response

```
abstract class DataState<T> {
  late final T? data;
  late final String? error;

  DataState(this.data, this.error);
}

class DataSuccess<T> extends DataState<T> {
  DataSuccess({required T data}) : super(data, null);
}

class DataFailed<T> extends DataState<T> {
  DataFailed({required String error}) : super(null, error);
}

class DataLoading<T> extends DataState<T> {
  DataLoading() : super(null, null);
}
```